# can't retrieve specific element from from xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, parsing, dom

I am having an issue trying to get a specific element from an xml file.
See below the javascript code i use and then the xml file.
More specifically, when i retrieve the title element of the first monument element its fine. The problem is when i try to retrieve the title element of the second monument element of the xml file.
The second alert shows nothing.What i do wrong? There is something wrong inside my for loop i guess.

javascript file

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc(doc) { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
            request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        } else { 
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        } 
        request.open("GET",doc,false); 
        request.send(""); 
        return request.responseXML; 
    }

    function displaypafosmonuments(doc) {
        xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc(doc);
        pafos=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("pafos");
        monuments=pafos[0].getElementsByTagName("monuments");

        monument=monuments[0].getElementsByTagName("monument");

        var title = new Array(3);
for(var k=0;k<2;k++){
title.push(monument[k].getElementsByTagName("title"));
alert(title[k].nodeName);
                   }
    }
</script>
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>    
    <pafos>
        <monuments>
            <monument>
                <username>dimitris</username>
                <email>katitis@gmail.com</email>
                <title>Colossi Castle</title>
                <description>Very nice castle</description>
                <image>colossi.jpg</image>
                <geolocation></geolocation>
                <date>08/03/2014</date>
                <time>01:33</time>
            </monument>
            <monument>
                <username>aristi</username>
                <email>kati@gmail.com</email>
                <title>Castle</title>
                <description>Very ugly castle</description>
                <image>colossi.jpg</image>
                <geolocation></geolocation>
                <date>09/03/2014</date>
                <time>02:33</time>
            </monument>
        </monuments>
    </pafos>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array with three empty places, and then inside the loop you push two more items. Now your array has five elements. But you read the first and the second, which are null.

One way to fix it is to change your array declaration:

```
var title = new Array();
```

Now you will be pushing elements 0 and 1, and reading elements 0 and 1.

Inside the loop you are reading the `title` node-set. You have to get the first (and only) title element.

```
title.push(monument[k].getElementsByTagName("title")[0]);
```

Finally, your `alert()` is not accessing the text node. So this will work:

alert(title[k].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/4sZ8x/1/

Comment: thanks a lot! you are right. my actual problem is when i try to do this in a for loop. can you check my edited post and tell me what is wrong now? i have the same issue in the for loop

Comment: I see. You are pushing two more elements on an array of size 3 and then reading the first two, which would be null. You also aren't adding the title, but the node-set. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: thanks again. i will use firebug from now on, i am new to javascript and xml.

Comment: but i don't push more elements. i removed the other lines for adding elements to that array and i replaced them by adding the elements inside the for loop

Comment: Check the fiddle link I posted. When you post CSS, JavaScript and HTML questions in Stack Overflow, always add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) since that makes it easier for us to test it. It's usually possible to adapt the problem to fit there.

Comment: i have a question regarding the line "title.push(monument[k].getElementsByTagName("title")[0]);". if i had more than one title elements inside the monument element in the xml file, then how i would add those elements to an array?in the same way as above, or would i have to change it to "title.push(monument[k].getElementsByTagName("title")[k]);" ;

Comment: You would make a separate loop inside it, since the number `n` of title elements won't necessarily be the same as the number `k` of monuments.